# How to refresh a data extension on a timer?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, automation, automationstudio

How do I setup a filtered data extension to automatically refresh on a daily basis at a specific time? Can I use Automation Studio to achieve this?

Comment: To help other users easily see your question has been answered, please accept my answer as you indicated that this helped you.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using a data filter activity in a scheduled automation. For more information see the following documentation:

- [Marketing Cloud Help: Create a Filter Activity](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/use_a_filter_activity/filter_subscribers_or_contacts/)
- [Marketing Cloud Help: Filter Activity](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/filter_activity/)
- [Marketing Cloud Help: Data Filters](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/data_filters/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

When attempting to access the automation studio, I select [Create Automation > Scheduled]. I'm presented with a list of activities on the left. I  select [Filter] and drag it into the workspace. I'm then prompted to choose a filter, however the list is blank when I expand the folder. I have created a large number of filters via Email Studio, but none are present.

Comment: All my filters are available in Automation Studio and unfortunately I wasn't able to reproduce your issue. Maybe you should ask this as a separate question.

Comment: You need to create Data Filter Activities from your Data Filters first before that will be available for use within Automation Studio.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is correct, you cannot see the the filters you have created because you probably created 'Data filters' and not 'Filter activities' after that in interactions.
Create the filter activity in interactions and then you will be able to select the filters you want in Automation Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this isn't possible through Automation Studio (well, I am sure it is with e.g. SSJS but not directly on the interface). There is an idea submitted to improve this so feel free to vote up for it:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003XY7QAM